# How do I sign an apk for release?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, playback

When I upload it to the Google Play Store, it tells me it's been signed in debug mode and needs to be signed in release mode.

I only have the apk file and unfortunately lost the source files.

Comment: You need the source code for it. Read this : https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: You need source code, is this true this is your app and you don't have its code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to decompile your apk and restore your source code then signed it
[Decompile Apk and Dex Android files to Java](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk)

Answer (score 0):

First of login to google console and get keygen.

In keygen property file, enter the credential like

```
key.store=debug.keystore
key.alias=androiddebugkey
key.store.password=abc
key.alias.password=abc
```

Also download keystore file from google console and place it in /app folder.

After then, run the command as -

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

This will create sign release apk in output folder

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add it in playstore without having source code.
Anyway , in future , you will need source code in order to make updates to the 
app .
For next projects try to use git in order to keep your projects.

Are you the author of this app ?  From where do you have the apk ? Did not generate it ? Apk is in general in project output folder . Or do you have this apk from someone and you want to put it in play ?